# How to search on fixed document?

Tags: wpf, search, document, fixed, viewer

In WPF, is there a way to search on fixed document? If possible, how to highlight the keyword?

The only way I know is to use the "Find" Control on Document Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there is still no way to programmatically use the search function in DocumentViewer. See [Daniel Palme's blog post](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2010/1/14/wpf-search-and-highlight-text-in-documentviewer-programmatically) for a workaround that uses reflection to access the "Find" toolbar programmatically.